# Rotate a vector in right direction using std::rotate()

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

How to rotate a vector in right direction by K steps using std::rotate? Is there a better or faster method to rotate a vector(array) than std::rotate?

Comment: you can use `rotate(v.begin(),v.begin()+v.size()-K,v.end())`, This gives the initial point of rotation to be k positions from the start and it would take the elements behind the Kth index towards the front

Comment: Best case would be accessing all elements of the array a fixed number of times (since all elements need to be moved).   That means complexity O(n) where n is the number of elements (and is independent of the number of steps).  `std::rotate()` is specified as having that complexity.   Your chances of finding a method that can do better are poor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to rotate a vector in right direction by K steps using std::rotate?

The second parameter to `std::rotate` is an iterator to the new first element after the rotation. So, to do a right rotate by `1` step, that would mean the `end() - 1` should be the new first etc.

Generalized:

```cpp
template<class... T>
void rotate_right(std::vector<T...>& v, std::size_t steps) {
    if(steps %= v.size())
        std::rotate(v.begin(), std::prev(v.end(), steps), v.end());
}
```

> Is there a better or faster method to rotate a vector(array) than std::rotate?

No, I don't think there is. If you find it too slow, you could use the version that uses one of the parallel execution policies and see if that speeds it up. Example:

```cpp
#include <execution>

template<class... T>
void rotate_right(std::vector<T...>& v, std::size_t steps) {
    if(steps %= v.size())
        std::rotate(std::execution::par, v.begin(), std::prev(v.end(), steps), v.end());
}
```

Comment: Will this work when (steps>size of vector) ?

Comment: @VaibhavVishalSingh Yes, with my edited answer.

Comment: _"so, to do a right rotate by 1 step, that would mean the end() - 1 should be the new first"_ But why is it not `begin() + 1`? `end() - 1` is going to the left to me. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @Sz. I'm not sure I understand. A right rotation by one step must make the last element the first element, right? Perhaps [`std::rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) clears it up.

Comment: Ahh, you replied too fast, so I couldn't fix the mistaken addendum to my comment about that bogus `end()-1`... :) OTOH, the point is: `{ 1, 2, 3, 4 }` rotated right is `{ 4, 1, 2, 3 }`. "Old first" is 1, at `begin()`, "new first" is also 1, but at `begin() + 1`. I've been at the CPPref page before, which outright says _"performs a left rotatation"_ in the description, plus the example for right rot. does use `begin() + 1`. So, I'm obviously misunderstanding the narrative here somehow. :) (The strange wording of "Rotate a vector in right direction" in the q. may be the clue, but not sure how.)

Comment: @Sz. The best part of the cppreference page is in my opinion _"`std::rotate` swaps the elements in the range `[first, last)` in such a way that the elements in `[first, middle)` are placed after the elements in `[middle, last)` while the orders of the elements in both ranges are preserved"_ - which shound't leave any doubts.

Comment: OK, the answer to my own question is the difference in iterator directions. The common-sense, natural value of "new first" is indeed `begin() + 1` (as in the `std::rotate` example for right rot.), but that requires using `reverse_iterator`s...

Comment: @Sz. Putting `begin() + 1` first would be a _left_ rotation. Just forget about directions and focus on the part I quoted. It's "direction-less".

Comment: OK, I'm puzzled again, but now about why you seem to consistently ignore the "canonical" example on that page: `simple rotation to the right`:
`std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());` :) _(Mind you, i misspelled `rbegin() + 1` above, focusing on the positions, not the directions, indeed.)_

Comment: @Sz. What part of the example am I ignoring? `// simple rotation to the left`
    `std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end());` seems to agree with all that I've said. Again, forget about directions. They are only a distraction.

Comment: Ahh, OK, I finally understand where my interpretation went astray... (partly due to the falsely reaffirming "help" of that right rot. example). Thanks for your patience!